# How to delete lines from a text file?

Tags: python

How can I make this work to delete values from my txt file? 
I have an 11 line file of 4 digit numbers, I can add but am stuck on deleting.

```
def delete_file(string_in):
    print("deleted_from_file")
    with open('test.txt', 'a+') as f:
        d = f.readlines()
        f.seek(11)
        for i in d:
            if i != " item = {} ":
            f.write(i)

    f.close()
```

Comment: Please give the question a title specific to your problem -- everyone posting here is stuck.

Comment: What is the `string_in` parameter for?

Comment: thats my file name

Comment: So it should be `open(string_in)` instead of `open('test.txt')`?

Answer (score 3):

`a+` mode means to write at the end of the file. So the seek has no effect, it always writes the lines after all the existing lines.

It would be easier to just open the file separately for reading and writing. Otherwise you also need to truncate the file after all the writes.

BTW, you don't need to use `f.close()` when you use `with` -- it automatically closes (that's the whole point).

The lines returned by `readlines()` end with newlines, you need to strip those off before comparing with the string.

```
def delete_file(string_in):
    print("deleted_from_file")
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        d = f.readlines()
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i in d:
            if i.rstrip('\n') != " item = {} ":
                f.write(i)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to only store the lines we need into memory?

Comment: @AnnZen This is a good answer as it stands. Barmar has judged his audience well and for sake of clarity has resisted the temptation of additional refactoring and optimisation.

Comment: @alaniwi I'm not judging him. I find it funny you call optimizing a temptation that needs to be resisted.

Comment: @AnnZen There is a time and place. The point is that by closely resembling the OP's code except in the points he is actually making (rather than all the points he conceivably *could* make), it is very easy to follow.

Comment: @alaniwi I agree that his answer is good, but that shouldn't stop me from giving my advice.

Comment: I didn't make the change because it essentially duplicates your answer. I agree that that's the better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the needed lines into a list using a list comprehension,
 and then write the lines into the file again after the file empties out:

```
def delete_file(string_in):
    print("deleted_from_file")
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        d = [i for i in f if i.strip('\n') != " item = {} "]
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(''.join(d))
```